# Can we bind a reference to a return value of a function?

Tags: c++

here is my question:

I have two classes `Vector` and `Matrix`, and I have define two functions, one to calculate the multiplication of a vector and a matrix and the other is to assign the value to a new vector.

Here is the code:

```
  file: Matrix.cpp
  Vector Matrix::operator*(const Vector& v)const {
      assert(v.length == numRows);
      Vector temp(v.length);
      for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
          for (int k = 0; k < v.length; k++)
              temp.contents[j] += v.contents[k] * contents[k][j];
      return temp;
  };

  file: Vector.cpp
  Vector& Vector::operator=(Vector& v){
      assert(v.length == length);
      if (&v != this) {
          for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
              setComponent(i, v.contents[i]);
      }
      return *this;
   };
```

Suppose I have well defined a 4*4 matrix `m1` and a 1*4 vector `v1`
Here is part of my code in `main()` function,

```
  file: main.app
  Vector v2(4);
  v2 = m1 * v1;
```

It can compile but will encounter a problem.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to deal with this? Is it because that I am trying to bind a reference with a return value of a function? Thanks so much!

Comment: [anonymus variables](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/814-anonymous-variables-and-objects/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You `assert(v.length == numRows);` but indexing to `numCols`

Comment: According to C++ standard your code should not compile at all because `m1 * v1` is an `rvalue` but `Vector&` is a non-const `lvalue` reference. Looks like MS Visual C++ bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing an address of 0x00....04 is an offset of 4 bytes from a null ptr.  It means that you are trying to write through an uninitialized pointer.  If you use a debugger, you can find the exact code trying to do this.

Comment: Hi @Juan , thanks for your reply, but where is the debugger in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: It is built into the GUI interface.  You build a Debug version of the software and then run it in the debugger.  There are many websites online which demonstrate how to do this, and give good tips for using the software.

Answer (score 1):

In you code you defined the assignment operator like this `Vector& Vector::operator=(Vector &v)`.  But it should be like `Vector& Vector::operator=(Vector const & v)`.  The reason is that `Vector &v` refers to an `lvalue` reference. But `m1 * v1` returns a `rvalue`.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that you are not having name clash with std::vector.
Presume you have constructor, copy constructor (given below, also needed assignment operator) that allocates properly and initializes all elements to zero

```
Vector::Vector(int sz) {
  contents = new int[length = sz]; // allocation
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
    contents[i] = 0;
  }
}

Vector::Vector(const Vector& v) {
  contents = new int[length = v.length]; // allocation
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    contents[i] = v.contents[i];
  }
}

Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
  contents = new int *[numRows = rows]; // allocation
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    contents[i] = new int[numCols = cols]; // allocation
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      contents[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& m) {
  contents = new int *[numRows = m.numRows]; // allocation
  for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    contents[i] = new int[numCols = m.numCols]; // allocation
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
      contents[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```